# Indexes all Exist in non Primary Filegroup - Advantages?

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2016, filegroups

I have come across a database where all the indexes are stored on a filegroup that is not the primary filegroup.

The database has 4 files, one of which is in the primary filegroup and the other 3 are in another filegroup, let's call it FileGroupB.

All the indexes are in FileGroupB according to this query:

```
SELECT  i.name,
        i.type_desc,
        o.name,
        f.name,
        o.type_desc
FROM    [sys].[indexes] i
        JOIN [sys].[filegroups] f
            ON f.[data_space_id] = i.[data_space_id]
        JOIN sys.objects o
            ON o.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE   o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

If I am correct, that would mean all code definitions (EG stored procs, functions etc) are stored in the primary file but all the data is in the secondary filegroup.

What is the benefit of / thought behind this approach?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I can list any benefits but that was fashionable about 15 to 20 years ago.

Well actually the db is accessible once the Primary Filegroup is online (if you have enterprise edition) - so you might be back online faster (albeit without any access to your data).

Answer (score 0):

It is to spread the data access out to different files and improve concurrent access between the index data and the table data.

Code definitions are just that anyway - code definitions. With FILEGROUPS I'd be more concerned with the files supporting them - how many to get the proportional fill across many data files per filegroup optimising my disk access.